How do I delete flatpak with including apps data?
How do I delete flatpak with data of the apps I downloaded.
Example I need to delete Sober or Roblox.

That will depend on the individual app. Generally, user data is not touched when an app is uninstalled. Things that the app put in its own caches, however, might. (for example, you wouldn't want uninstalling LibreOffice to delete all your Documents, would you? Games are no different from the point of view of flatpak.)
